# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null?

Tags: php, mysqli, null

```
       <?
         include_once("conexion.php"); 
         ?>
     
         <html>
         <head>    
                 <title>Pedidos</title>
                 <meta charset="UTF-8">
             <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
             <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet">
         </head>
         <body>
         <?php
         error_reporting(E_ALL);
         ini_set('display_errors', '1');
         ?>
     
             <table>
                 <nav>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="check">
                 <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                     <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                 </label>
                 <a href="#" class="enlace">
                     <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
                 </a>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                     <li><a class="nosotros" href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
                     <li><a href="index4.php">CDS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="index3.php">ClienteS</a></li>
                     <li><a class="active" href="index2.php">Pedidos</a></li>
     
                      </ul>
              </nav>
               <table>
                 <div id="barrabuscar">
                 <form method="POST">
                 <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="btnbuscar"><input type="text" name="txtbuscar" id="cajabuscar"
 placeholder="&#128270;Ingresar nombre de usuario">
                 </form>
                 </div>
                     </div>
                 <div class="lista">
                     <tr><th colspan="6"><h1>Planilla de pedidos </h1><th><a style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px;"
 onclick="abrirform()">Hacer pedido</a></th></tr>
                     <tr>
                    <th>Nro</th>
                    <th>Id_cliente</th>
                     <th>Id_pedido</th>
                     <th>Nombre del CD</th>
                     <th>Id_ del CD</th>
                     <th>Unidades</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                    </tr>
         <?php 
     
         if(isset($_POST['btnbuscar']))
         {
             $buscar = $_POST['txtbuscar'];
         $queryusuarios = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_cliente,codigo,producto,id_producto,unidades FROM usuarios where
 nombre like '".$buscar."%'");
         }
         else
         {
                 global $conn;
         $queryusuarios = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY codigo asc");
         }
                $numerofila = 0;
                 while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($queryusuarios))
                {    
                     $numerofila++;    
                     echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<td>".$numerofila."</td>";
                     echo "<td>".$mostrar['id_cliente']."</td>";
                     echo "<td>".$mostrar['codigo']."</td>";
                     echo "<td>".$mostrar['producto']."</td>";
                     echo "<td>".$mostrar['id_producto']."</td>";
                     echo "<td>".$mostrar['unidades']."</td>";      
                     echo "<td style='width:15%'>
                     <a href=\"editar.php?codigo=$mostrar[codigo]\">Modificar</a> | <a
 href=\"eliminar.php?codigo=$mostrar[codigo]\" onClick=\"return
 confirm('Â¿EstÃ¡s seguro de eliminar a
 $mostrar[id_cliente]?')\">Eliminar</a></td>";           
         }
         ?>
             </table>
     
         <script>
         function abrirform() {
           document.getElementById("formregistrar").style.display = "block";
           
         }
     
         function cancelarform() {
           document.getElementById("formregistrar").style.display = "none";
         }
     
         </script>
     
         <div class="caja_popup" id="formregistrar">
           <form action="agregar.php" class="contenedor_popup" method="POST">
                 <table>
                <tr><th colspan="2">Registrar Pedidos</th></tr>
                 <tr>  
                     <td>id_cliente</td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="txtid_cliente" required></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr> 
                         <td>nombre del cd</td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="txtproducto" required></td>
                     </tr>
                    <tr>  
                     <td>id_del CD</td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="txtid_producto" required></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr> 
                         <td>unidades</td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="txtunidades" required></td>
                     </tr>
                    
                     <tr>   
                        <td colspan="5">
                           <button type="button" onclick="cancelarform()">Cancelar</button>
                           <input type="submit" name="btnregistrar" value="Registrar" onClick="javascript: return confirm('Â¿Deseas
 registrar a este usuario?');">
                    </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </form>
         </div>
         </body>
         </html>
```

**El error está en la linea 66:

$queryusuarios = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY codigo asc");

Ya modifiqué los errores anteriores y solo queda este y no logro descifrarlo.
**
[image: Como veran es el unico error de la pagina web, lo demas anda, pero si no resuelvo este error no puedo ingresar registros, lo cual es la funcion principal de este programa]

Comment: y $conn que contiene de donde viene? puedes colocarlo?

Comment: Holaa, si obvio.                                                                                                    <?
$conn = new mysqli()("localhost","root","","escuela");
 
 if($conn->connect_errno)
 {
  echo "No hay conexión: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
 }
?>

Comment: ¿Aparece mensaje de error al conectar? Si no, probablemente estás tratando de usar la variable en un ámbito donde no está disponible, por ejemplo, dentro de una función o método de clase, donde debes recibirla como parámetro o, nada recomendable, agregar al inicio de la función `global $conn;`

Comment: @JulietaMartinez as incluido el archivo donde se encuentra `$conn` en `index2.php`?

Comment: @Bryro si, lo inclui al inicio, de esta forma: include_once("conexion.php");

Comment: @Triby Lo que yo entiendo es que $conn es nulo, pero ya lo declaré en conexion.php

Comment: @Triby <?
$conn = new mysqli()("localhost","root","","escuela");
 
 if($conn->connect_errno)
 {
  echo "No hay conexión: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
 }
?>

Comment: ¿Tienes habilitada la opción para etiquetas cortas? De lo contrario, debes iniciar con `<?php` en lugar de solo `<?`

Comment: @Triby sisi la tengo habilitada, igualmente probé de las 2 formas.

Comment: Entonces usa el método adecuado: `$conn->query()` porque realizaste la conexión creando un objeto. Revisa en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) el ejemplo con estilo orientado a objetos.

Answer (score 1):

## primer error

tienes esto:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli()("localhost","root","","escuela");
       if($conn->connect_errno){
          echo "No hay conexión: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
      }
 ?>
```

pero debes ser asi:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","escuela");
       if($conn->connect_errno){
          echo "No hay conexión: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
      }
 ?>
```

como ves tiene unos parentesis de mas.

lo raro es que no te marco error por ello.

## segundo error

creas un objeto conexion con new mysqli

pero utilizas en procedurar debes utilizar uno u otro.

recomiendo ver el manual ya que utilizas ambas formas en tu codigo

puedes ver la documentacion en [mysqli query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

**procedural**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","escuela");
/// resto codigo
$queryusuarios = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY codigo asc");
// resto del codigo
while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($queryusuarios))
```

**Objeto:**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","escuela");
/// resto del codigo
$queryusuarios = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY codigo asc");
// resto del codigo
while($mostrar = $queryusuarios->fetch_assoc())
```

## tercer error:

la apertura correcta es:

```
 <?php
     include_once("conexion.php"); 
  ?>
```

como ves te falta el php al incio del tag por ello lo toma como texto plano y no lo interpreta correctamente!

## cuarto error

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
```

siempre va al principio del documento antes que cualquier cosa, esto para que muestre todos los errores!

Comment: Ya borre esos 2 paréntesis pero el error sigue. Ese error estaba en "conexion.php" y mi error esta en "index2.php"

Comment: Utilicé el metodo objeto, el error ahora se acortó: Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\julieta\index2.php:66 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\julieta\index2.php
on line
66

Comment: Sugiero que en lugar de `echo` uses `die()` cuando hay error en la conexión, parece que es lo único que falta para saber cuál es exactamente el problema... entre todos los que había antes. xD

Comment: @JulietaMartinez en tu pregunta debes colocar el codigo ya que si la pregunta no se puede depurar tan fasil se mandara a cerrar y marcara como `Necesita ser más específica` o `Necesita detalles o aclaraciones` o `Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado ...` asi que recomiendo edites y agreges el resto del codigo!

Comment: ¡Ah! La otra cosa que falta por resolver es si trata de acceder a `$conn` dentro de una función.

Comment: @Bryro ya lo edite! es muy largo y no pude ponerlo en formato de codigo, espero que igual se entienda

Comment: @JulietaMartinez listo!

Comment: @Bryro no entiendo el 4to error

Comment: @JulietaMartinez explicado!